# How can I transition a square duct to round of the same outer size?

Tags: hvac, ducts

In remodeling my bathroom I had to convert a 6"x6" square duct underneath the floor joists in the basement to flex so I can get around my new toiler drain. I cannot for the life of me find a 6"x6" square to 6" round transition anywhere.

Do I need to fabricate one myself? I don't know what to do.

I am aware that a 6" round duct is smaller than 6"x6" square by ~20%. It feeds the foyer which I have kept the damper nearly closed anyways because it gets very hot/cold in that location.

Comment: Why not flexible square duct? It bends in all directions just like the round one.

Comment: Check amazon, here is one, probably more. https://www.amazon.com/Outlet-Ceiling-Square-drywall-flange/dp/B00NG3HZUQ/ref=sr_1_9?s=hi&ie=UTF8&qid=1487792530&sr=1-9&keywords=Square+to+Round+6%22

Answer (score 22):

They do exist. Best bet is probably to contact a local sheet metal shop, if they don't have one they can build one. Expect this to cost in the tens of dollars range.

[image]

---

You could potentially cap the end, and then use a round duct takeoff. The downside is it will restrict flow to the vent because of the abrupt end and sharp angles internally.

[image]

---

There's another type of side takeoff that is rectangular, and if you can find one you could potentially modify it yourself using a couple strategic cuts and copious amounts of foil tape.

[image]

Comment: I agree that contacting a local shop might be a good solution.  It's not a very complicated or uncommon part for a shop (the sizes might throw them off slightly).

Comment: Called a local shop and he has a 6x6x6 ceiling box that he said should do the job, I'm going to swing by today and pick it up.  Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 5):

You'd just cap the square duct and install a takeoff in the cap. It may be difficult to find a hemmed end cap in 6x6, but as you can imagine it would be trivial to fabricate a simple wraparound cap.

[image]